# Payment Methods Missing at Checkout

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, paypal, amazon-payment

I had my site configured to accept payments from PayPal, Amazon, and Authorized net.  Everything was working great.  Last week, I upgraded to Magento 2.3.1 and installed Affirm as a payment method.  I tried switching to a basic Magento theme to see if it was a bug in the theme, but it has the same issue.

After that, Affirm is the only payment option.

[image: affirm only]

As far as I can tell, these other payment options are still enabled.

Eg. Here is the amazon setting.  The creds were still there.  Login with amazon is working.
[image]

I tried flushing the caches, I've tried recompiling the site.  Still no dice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried disabling affirm?  Use the module disable console command. Clear everything after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue with Magento 2.3.1. Updating to 2.3.2 should solve the issue.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The issue is a flaw with the retrieval of the relevant configuration in the extension. Fix: https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/commit/ba4fe0f1d06b71d85caf38294e10aa0533989564

Comment: I just installed 2.3.2, so I will verify if it resolved the issue.

Comment: I confirmed this resolved the issue.